# How to set a timer for CSS animation-timing-function?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Ok, imagine you have created animation with ease-out effect and you set duration for 2s (eg):

```
animation-name: example;
animation-timing-function: ease-out;
animation-duration: 2s;
```

Animation-duration property specifies how many seconds an animation takes to complete one cycle, but I was not able to find solution ***how to (for example) slow down only "ease-out" part of animation.***

Here is a fiddle example of simple animation, so you everything ready to test your ideas (if it is even possible?!): https://jsfiddle.net/3nbr6LhL/

(Feel free to use js if you like).
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to slow down only "ease-out" part of animation?**

You cannot slow down *only* the ease-out part of the animation as `ease-out` is a built-in reference to a [bezier-curve timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function), which defines the behaviour of the 1d transform of a CSS property's value for the *whole duration* of the animation:

> *<timing-function>*
>
> The  CSS data type denotes a mathematical function that describes how fast one-dimensional values change during transitions or animations. This in essence lets you establish an acceleration curve, so that the speed of the animation can vary over its duration. These functions are often called easing functions.

What you can do is create your own bezier-curve using a tool like [cubic-bezier.com](http://cubic-bezier.com/), amending the [`ease-out` curve](http://cubic-bezier.com/#0,0,.58,1) as you see fit. For example, [here is a slower ease-out timing function](http://cubic-bezier.com/#0,0,.8,.45):

```
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, .8, .45);
```

[ [See working in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nbr6LhL/1/) ]

______

**How to set a timer for CSS animation-timing-function?**

The answer to this depends on what you mean by *setting a timer*. If you want to *delay* the animation then you can use the [`animation-delay` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay). For example, to delay an animation by three seconds:

```
animation-delay: 3s;
```

[ [See working in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nbr6LhL/2/) ]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom timing function instead of `ease-out` to exactly control the speed of the animation.

Take a look at [this CSS EASING ANIMATION TOOL named Ceaser](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/).